# Bind to NIC but i want ephemeral source port (windows C)

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, udp

I am setting up UDP communication between 2 devices. I am working on the client (sending) portion, and i followed the example here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#Client-server_example_using_UDP

I am trying to to set this up where the sends go to the destination address and port, from a binded address but an ephemeral src port. I All works fine when i do exactly as this example shows, but the src port matches the dest port. With tcp, setting the    sa.sin_port  to 0 causes it to use ephemeral src port, and when i tried this with the UDP bind, messages get sent out, but received messages don't seem to arrive properly. is there a trick to doing udp bind with ephemeral src port? I looked all over and couldnt find the answer..

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by "don't seem to arrive properly"?

Comment: You cannot bind before a sendto call and also have an ephemeral src port. It is one or the other. The client must send to a destination port and the server must bind & recvfrom on that same port. You do not need to call bind before sendto on the client side as an ephemeral src port will be set by the sendto call. On the server side, binding to zero will allow you to bind to an ip address and recvfrom will use any available port.